# SharePoint web part to show business card

Tags: 2010, web-part, my-site, business-card

In our portal envirionment, there are a lot of users that would like to display some personal information on a lot of webpages like contact info.

Ofcourse these people could type all this info down on each site but the ideal situation would be to have a web part that displays a business card or something that uses data from the my sites! This has a lot of advantages like improved managability etc.

So my question is do you know of a web part that can be used for this purpose or where i can get one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a contactfieldcontrol web part that allows you to specify the user you wish to display information about. It display name, profile picture and job title. Clicking through on the persons name/image will take you to their mysite. OOTB that would seem like the best option.

Comment: This sounds like it is exactly what we are looking for,but i can't seem to find it in the list of web parts... Where can i find it?

Comment: in the web part gallery goto new document and then down the list search for contactfieldcontrol